# Spring mvc: Object as property of another class validation JSR 300

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have a table `employee` having `department` and `address` as its property. I want to validate the attributes of `address` class with JSR 300. But i have problem with validation with attributes of address and department class. So far, only the attributes of `Employee` class is being validated. Am i missing something?

```
public class Employee {

    private Integer id;
    @NotEmpty(message = "First Name must not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Last Name must not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Digits(message = "Salary field must not be blank.", integer=32767, fraction = 2)
    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
    @NotNull(message = "Salary field must not be blank.")
    private Double salary;

    @Digits(message = "Select department", integer=100, fraction = 0)
    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
    @NotNull(message = "Select department")
    private Integer dept_id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Select gender")
    private String gender;
    private boolean employeeStatus;
    private Address address;
    private Department department;
}

public class Address {

    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Country must not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String country;

    @NotEmpty(message = "City must not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String city;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Street must not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String street;
    private Integer emp_id;

    }

public class Department {

    private String name;
    private Integer id;

}
```

**jsp**

```
<form:form commandName="employee" action="addEmployee.htm"
            name="employeeForm">
            <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
            <fieldset>
                <form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label>
                <form:input path="firstName" />
                <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" />
                <br>

                <form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label>
                <form:input path="lastName" />
                <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" />
                <br>

                <form:label path="address.country">Country</form:label>
                <form:input path="address.country" />
                <form:errors path="address.country" cssClass="error" />
                <br>

                <form:label path="address.city">City</form:label>
                <form:input path="address.city" />
                <form:errors path="address.city" cssClass="error" />
                <br>

                <form:label path="address.street">Street</form:label>
                <form:input path="address.street" />
                <form:errors path="address.street" cssClass="error" />
                <br>

                <form:label path="salary">Salary</form:label>
                <form:input path="salary" />
                <form:errors path="salary" cssClass="error" />
                <br>

                <form:label path="gender">Gender</form:label>
                <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="Male" />
                Male
                <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="Female" />
                Female
                <form:errors path="gender" cssClass="error" />

                <form:label path="dept_id">Department</form:label>

                <form:select path="dept_id">
                    <form:option value="" label="Please Select"></form:option>
                    <form:options items="${departmentList}" itemValue="id"
                        itemLabel="name" />
                </form:select>
                <form:errors path="dept_id" cssClass="error" />

                <label></label><input type="submit" value="Add Employee"><br>
            </fieldset>


        </form:form>
```

Moreover, when i try random string in salary field i get an exception.

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Double for property salary; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException:
```

How to get rid of this exception?

Comment: how you resolve the exception on department field, i'm gotten:
`Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type org.abc.model.entities.Department for property department; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String]..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `@Valid` attribute for constraint composition. This way, all constraints in `Address` will be evaluated:

```
@Valid
 private Address address;
```

As far as the formatting exception, it is not clear to me how or where you are getting that error but other than validating the  model in your controller (using the `@Valid` attribute before your controller's method parameter) I would suggest using `CURRENCY` for money (salary):

```
@NumberFormat(style=Style.CURRENCY)
```